# Using Skin file, Unable to set difference between enabled and disabled button

Tags: asp.net, stylesheet, skinning

I've got a skin file to set my button properties, however when I set a button with the status enabled to false, the button still shows up the same as before in most browsers.

Is there a way I can change the button Skin when a button is set to be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers will automatically style disabled elements for you. If you want to modify the default styles in your stylesheet, you can target disabled elements using:

```
input[disabled='disabled'] {
  ... styles go here ... 
}
```

Comment: this won't work if the element is inline-styled from server. you can't replace those properties values with css